# My PWA using Workbox CLI and its service-worker generator doesn't work offline

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm newbie in building PWAs and working with Workbox (V5). And I'm having problem making my page to be cached and work offline!

Here is what I have done:

1. I wrote my **index.html** file in a way that it has the needed meta tags for PWAs, loads the manifest file (*manifest.webmanifest*), and registers the service-worker JavaScript file (*sw.js*).
2. I installed **workbox-cli** using `npm install workbox-cli --global` command.
3. I generated my **workbox-config.js** file using `workbox wizard` command and tweaked it manually to fit my desire configurations.
4. I finally generated my service-worker (*sw.js*) file and a *workbox-xxx.js* file using `workbox generateSW workbox-config.js` command.

Now when I run my page on localhost and then open up the *Chrome DevTools*, and go to *Lighthouse* section to audit my webpage with it, it says my app is installable, and PWA optimized... But says it doesn't work offline:

```
- Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline

- start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineTimed out waiting for start_url (http://127.0.0.1:4000/?source=pwa) to respond.
```

Here is my **index.html**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#eeeeee" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Hello" />
  <meta name="description" content="I'm here. Hello World!" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#eeeeee" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./apple-touch-icon.png">


  <title>Hello</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Hello World!">
  <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/main.css">
</head>


  <body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <script src="./assets/scripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
    // Check that service workers are supported
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js');
      });
    }
    </script>

    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my **manifest.webmanifest**.

```
{
  "short_name": "Hello",
  "name": "Hello",
  "description": "I'm here. Hello World!",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/?source=pwa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "theme_color": "#eeeeee",
  "background_color": "#eeeeee"
}
```

Here is my **workbox-config.js**. As you can see I only pre-cache *.html* and *.ico* files, and then do runtime caching for images or *.css* and *.js* files.

```
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: "./",
  globPatterns: [
    "**/*.{html,ico}"
  ],
  globIgnores: [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "{.,_}*/**/*",
    "**/*.{md,txt}",
    "Gemfile*",
    "package*"
  ],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
      handler: 'CacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'images',
        expiration: {
          maxEntries: 10,
          maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 Days
        },
      },
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\.(?:css|js)$/,
      handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'assets',
      },
    }
  ],
  swDest: "./sw.js",
  sourcemap: false
};
```

I cannot understand what am I doing wrong! Everything is clear and based on the Workbox documentations!
Please help! Anyone knows what's going wrong over here?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/^source$/]` to your `workbox-config.js`. This will tell `workbox-precaching` that the `?source=pwa` query parameter can be ignored when looking for a matching URL in the cache.

[By default](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ae29e1748bb976351db8e0c64a9ea9fc8ba2583f/packages/workbox-precaching/src/utils/generateURLVariations.ts#L25), anything starting with `utm_` or the parameter `fbclid` is ignored, so if you wanted, another approach would be to change your `start_url` to something like `/?utm_source=pwa`.

Comment: Cool! I've lost yesterday on this stupid query parameter! But today, you saved my day! The problem is solved and my app is working offline just fine. Thanks a heap bro :)

Comment: Sorry that you lost a day to this :-/ Here's an issue to track an improvement that will hopefully prevent similar issues in the future: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2758